# Gradle versions specification: using mancj/MaterialSearchBar with API lvl 27?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I am using [mancj/MaterialSearchBar](https://github.com/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/blob/master/README.md) to set up a search bar which looks like the Playstore's one. However, I'm having some trouble with my Gradle build.

## The error

[image]

## build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.."
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        renderscriptTargetApi 27
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.6'
}
```

## Solution tried

I already tried to replace the implementation of this API with the following line: `implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.6:27.1.1'` but it didn't find it (meaning it doesn't exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [library (version 0.7.6)](https://github.com/mancj/MaterialSearchBar/blob/master/library/build.gradle#L26-L28) is using 3 dependencies (AppCompat-v7, RecyclerView-v7 and CardView-v7) related to the version `25.4.0`.

Because you are already using `AppCompat-v7` and `RecyclerView` (RecyclerView is included into `Design`), the library is going to use the version 27 instead of 25.

You only have one more library to convert from 25 to 27, `CardView-v7`.

If to add `implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'`, 
this will force the library to use the version 27 instead of 25, and therefor allow you to compile.

You still need to take care by testing your app to see if its behavior is correct, as the library was not tested to use 27 yet.

Answer (score 1):

use latest version

```
implementation 'com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.8.2'
```

add this code to the the project level build.gradle file

```
 maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

Comment: Yes the author updated its API since I told him about this problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

one can substitute the conflicting version alike this (and hope it will still work with `27.1.1`):

```
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1"
implementation ("com.github.mancj:MaterialSearchBar:0.7.6") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "cardview-v7"
}
```